# Angular JS - Best Way to UI Testing Angular js projects

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have written a site with `angular js` and I now want to create UI tests for this site (Automated UI Test) but I don't know the best way to do this. Is using a Visual Studio Coded UI Test Project a good way of writing these tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karma is a nice tool to run UI tests with .
It Supports angularJs and javascript and also has nice customization capacities .
you can find out more about karma [here](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are looking for a way to test the application as a whole, the so-called end-2-end tests. If so, then I would recommend using protractor. Protractor is able to understand the Angular application that it tests so the results are highly trustworthy compared to other test suites.

check out: https://github.com/angular/protractor

Answer (score 1):

Are you use Microsoft MT Test?
I believe that can be useful for you.

Comment: I Use this but I need beter tool for angular js